# How to keep form at centre using bootstrap 2.2.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/130070) the welcome as well as the form is coming on the left hand side.But I want to bring it at the centre.Can any body please tell me how to do?

```
<form id="form1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1"></div>
                <div class="span10" style="margin-bottom: 6px; margin-top: 0px; background: #efeee9">
                    <img src="ui_resources/img/ title.jpg" alt="" align="left">
                    <h2 align="center" style="margin-top: 18px;"></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span1"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1"></div>
                <div class="span10" style="background: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd;">

                    <div class="span7 center login-header">
                    <h2 style="color:#E86537 " align="center">Welcome </h2>
                </div><!--/span-->
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="well span7 center login-box">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        Please login with your Username and Password.
                    </div>




                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Username" data-rel="tooltip" style="margin-left:80px;">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span><input autofocus="" class="input-large span10" name="j_username" id="username" type="text" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Password" data-rel="tooltip" style="margin-left:80px;">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span><input class="input-large span10" name="j_password" id="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:80px;">
                            <label class="remember" for="remember"><input type="checkbox" id="remember" style="display:">Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <p class="center span6" style="margin-left:80px;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            New User<a href="/NewPatient">register</a>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>

                </div><!--/span-->
            </div><!--/row-->


            </div><!--/row-->




                </div>
                <div class="span1"></div>
            </div></form>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1"></div>
                <div class="span10" style="margin-top: 6px;">
                <div class="span1"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your CSS

```
.row-fluid .login-header,
.row-fluid .login-box{
      float:none;
      margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,its working +1.well will it be responsive

Comment: It will be responsive because the above css doesn't alters any thing to remove the responsive behavior of the bootstrap's css

Answer (score 2):

try to set your welcome div in another div like this

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="offset3 span6 center login-header">
        <h2 style="color:#E86537 " align="center">Welcome </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

use [offset](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

> Move columns to the right using .offset* classes. Each class increases
>   the left margin of a column by a whole column. For example, .offset4
>   moves .span4 over four columns.

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/130080)

Comment: Thanks for answering +1,the demo you have provided has welcome at the centre but I want welcome along with the form at the centre

Answer (score 1):

Since `.span*` has `float: left` style by default, you can override it by using `float:none;`

```
.login-box {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
}
```

`margin:0 auto;` is used to center your `loginbox` horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for answering .I tried this but its not coming to centre